# Does GC.KeepAlive clean OnTimeEvent Variables and classes types?

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

I have a Timer function that I'm calling it from the **Application_Start in the global.asax**

this is the class:

```
public class AlertTimer
{
    public AlertTimer()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public static void Start()
    {
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 30000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }
    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        PresenceService ps = new PresenceService();
        ps.GetAbsenceContacts(); //takes 10 seconds
    }
}
```

Now , My question is if this class type **`PresenceService ps = new PresenceService();`** is getting clean after the timer done with the run, or  the GC is keeping it in the memory and start a new one every time that the OnTimedEvent run.

thanks!

**conclusion:** To remove GC from the code. Tnx!

Comment: GC.KeepAlive() extends the lifetime of a local variable.  It does nothing here, the aTimer variable is static so it lives *forever*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now , My question is if this class type PresenceService ps = new
>   PresenceService(); is getting clean after the timer done with the run,
>   or the GC is keeping it in the memory and start a new one every time
>   that the OnTimedEvent run.

Yes.

The instance of PresenceService will leave scope, and therefore be subject to garbage collection. However, since GC is mostly indeterministic, it is still in memory until such time as it's reclaimed. Therefore, on object's that do things and have life cycles (like timers for example) it's good to call some type of "shutdown" method.

However, the larger question I have is why you're running a timer in a web app and why you feel the need to call any methods directly on the Garbage collector. This is generally a sign that something is off about your application.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, Now for your question. I'm running a timer to check every 5 minutes if there is a change in the DataBase and do some action if if there are. Is this wrong to run the timer on the server? should I run a stand alone timer that runs a part of the web application?

Comment: Typically such tasks would be performed on an application server, by some type of services or otherwise regularly scheduled task. From the comments in the code it appears to be a heavy task, and it's never a good idea to tie up your web app with long running tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The `ps` instance will be eligible for garbage collection when `OnTimedEvent` ends.<sup>1</sup> Well, that is assuming, of course, that `PresenceService` does not somehow root its own reference (via a static variable, etc.).

Also, `GC.KeepAlive`  is not needed in this case. The reason is that `aTimer` is static so its lifetime is already tied to the application domain. In other words, `aTimer` is not eligible for collection at any point in the `Start` method because it is semi-permanently rooted by the static variable.

`GC.KeepAlive` is used in scenarios where the GC gets overly aggressive. When you compile the application with the release configuration and run it outside of the debugger the GC will mark object instances eligible for collection even before they go out of scope. For example, `ps` could be collected even before `GetAbsenceContracts` completes! `GC.KeepAlive` basically turns that optimization off. You typically see it used in unmanaged interop scenarios where you pass an object reference to an unmanaged API. Because the GC does not know anything about what is going on in the unmanaged realm it may mistakenly think the reference is no longer used and collect it prematurely.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Technically, this is not exactly correct. The instance is eligible for collection when the GC thinks it is no longer used. It really has little to do with whether or not it is still in scope.*

Comment: Thanks for the information you both right. I voted for the first! Thanks!